# What happened to Thumper?

Tags: time-travel, the-butterfly-effect

In the movie *The Butterfly Effect*, what happened to Thumper? Did he change or disappear?  Or did it form a different timeline which caused him to change into something else ?

Comment: Presumably, you mean to ask what happened to him in the final timeline shown. As we see, the changes to the timeline affect multiple people in different ways. There is no reason, however, to assume that he was wiped out of existence or made to disappear. We just never learn the fate of everyone.

Comment: It's been years since I saw it, but wasn't the implication that in the timeline where he never got the girl, everyone was ok?  I seem to remember that everything worked out except for their romance.  If so, that would probably apply to Thumper too.

Comment: thats my theory too thumper might have had a better life

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the answer to this is that *we don't really know.*

Thumper was a character that Evan met much later in life, specifically in college. In the original timeline, Thumper was "completely punked out Gothic boy who weighs 300 pounds." (From [the IMSDb script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Butterfly-Effect,-The.html)). His childhood would most likely have been unaffected by Evan's absence in childhood moments with the other children.

Even in the [alternate ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huWrQnVD-G4), where Evan strangles himself *in utero* via his umbilical cord, we see nothing about Thumper. So, unfortunately, this also gives us no information.

We also don't see if Evan went to the same school as Thumper in the final, altered timeline.

I tried finding interviews from the writers/directors Eric Bress & Mackye Gruber, but they never seem to have spoken about the minor characters.

Based on this, I would assume that Thumper stayed his Gothic self, not his "clean" version, at least at the time when he (would have) met Evan.